# Compare dates in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets

I have in a google spreadsheet:

- cell A1 contains `Wednesday 10 June 2015` as date
- cell A2 contains `Wednesday 10 June 2015` as text (that's the output of a google form, I can't choose the format)

How can I obtain TRUE when comparing these 2 cells?

I have tried

```
=A1=A2
```

and

```
=TEXT(A1)=A2
```

and

```
=A1=DATEVALUE(A2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following formula will convert your text date to number (dates actually are numbers)

```
=datevalue(MID(A2,FIND("day ",A2)+4,20))
```

So given above your formula should be

```
=A1=datevalue(MID(A2,FIND("day ",A2)+4,20))
```

How does it works?

The `MID`formula extracts the date in dd/mm/yyyy format. i.e it finds `"day "` in the cell and remove everything that's before it.

The `DATEVALUE` formula is used to convert a string (text) date into a numerical date.

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit weird that `datevalue` works with `10 June 2015` but not with `Wednesday 10 June 2015`, but why not.. Thank you for your help