# google Sheets count Date and Time

Tags: date, google-sheets, time, count, between

can plz someone help me to correct my Funktion
count number of cells with Date "Today" and Time "between 06:00 and 14:30"

```
=countifs('G:G">=Today() 06:00:00", 'G:G"<=Today() 14:30:00")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare dates in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465860/compare-dates-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER('JIRA_Input SL'!G:G; 
                    'JIRA_Input SL'!G:G>=(TODAY()+"06:00:00"); 
                    'JIRA_Input SL'!G:G<=(TODAY()+"14:30:00"))))
```

Comment: Thanx alot for your answer 
I try it but Unfortunately it didn't work


I try this Function for Day “today”
=COUNTIF('JIRA_Input SL'!G:G;">="&TODAY())-COUNTIF('JIRA_Input SL'!G:G;">="&TODAY()+1)


And this Function for Time “between  06:00 and 14:30”
=COUNTIFS('JIRA_Input SL'!G:G;">=06:00:00")-countifs('JIRA_Input SL'!G:G;"<=14:30:00")

Both of them is working but i need a Function for both of them together
I mean Is “it possible to combine the two functions together?”

Comment: @alaaalhamwi can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: yes sure
I need to add the Function on Sheet"Schichtübergabe" Cell"E22"


https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2k1QEPJiDftoryWc05wq_9nHeVXGG-3dxQ0blNITew/edit?usp=sharing

thanx alot.

Comment: @alaaalhamwi sheet is private

Comment: Sry now it's public  
@player0

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2k1QEPJiDftoryWc05wq_9nHeVXGG-3dxQ0blNITew/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @alaaalhamwi see your sheet. answer updated